# Compare current time with fixed time 05:00:00 PM

Tags: iphone, compare, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How will I compare current time [NSDate date] with fixed time 05:00:00 PM.

That 05:00 PM is already passed or not. I just need BOOL check for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)past5pm
{
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalender = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalender components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    if([components hour] >= 17) // NSDateComponents uses the 24 hours format in which 17 is 5pm
       return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH.mm"];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *curDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

if ([curDate doubleValue] >= 17.00) 
{
    //set your bool
}
```

Comment: Comparing a ObjC object with a double seems a bit wrong, don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];

        NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

        //Get the string date
        NSString* str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

        NSDate *firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"05:00:00 PM"];

        NSDate *secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];

        NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];

        NSLog(@"Time Diff - %f",timeDifference);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use plain C style code and get the difference as an integer and then decide what you need to return from the comparison function depending on wether the difference is positive or negative. You can compare minutes this way as well. Dont forget to import time.h.

```
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm oldCTime;
    localtime_r(&now, &oldCTime);
    int hours = oldCTime.tm_hour;
    int diff = 17-hours;
    NSLog(@"Time difference is: %d.", diff);
```